# Exercise 13, Section 5.2 of Hoffman’s Linear Algebra

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, solution-verification, proof-writing, determinant

> Let $\Bbb{R}$ be the field of real numbers, and let $D$ be a function on $2 \times 2$ matrices over $\Bbb{R}$, with values in $\Bbb{R}$, such that $D(AB) = D(A)D(B)$ for all $A, B$. Suppose
> also that $$D \left(\begin{bmatrix}0&1\\ 1&0\\ \end{bmatrix}\right)\neq D\left(\begin{bmatrix}1&0\\ 0&1\\ \end{bmatrix}\right)$$ Prove the following.
>
> (a) $D(0)=0$;
>
> (b) $D(A)=0$ if $A^2 = 0$;
>
> (c) $D(B) = -D(A)$ if $B$ is obtained by interchanging the rows (or columns) of $A$;
>
> (d) $D(A) = 0$ if one row (or one column) of $A$ is $0$;
>
> (e) $D(A) = 0$ whenever $A$ is singular.

**My attempt:** **(a)** Since $D(AB)=D(A)D(B)$, $\forall A,B\in M_2(\Bbb{R})$ and $D \left(\begin{bmatrix}0&1\\ 1&0\\ \end{bmatrix}\right)\neq D\left(\begin{bmatrix}1&0\\ 0&1\\ \end{bmatrix}\right)$, we have $D(I_2)=1$, by [exercise 12 section 5.2](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4533589/861687). By hypothesis, $D(0)=D(0)\cdot D(0)$. By elementary  properties of field, $D(0)\cdot (1-D(0))=0$. Which implies $D(0)=0$ or $D(0)=1$. If $D(0)=1$, then $$D(0) =D\left(\begin{bmatrix}0&1\\ 1&0\\ \end{bmatrix}\right)\cdot D(0)=1= D\left(\begin{bmatrix}0&1\\ 1&0\\ \end{bmatrix}\right)= D\left(\begin{bmatrix}1&0\\ 0&1\\ \end{bmatrix}\right).$$ Thus we reach contradiction. Hence $D(0)=0$.

**(b)** Suppose $A^2=0$. Then $D(A^2)$ $=D(A)\cdot D(A)$ $=D(0)$ $=0$. It’s easy to check, $(D(A))^2=0$$\iff$$D(A)=0$.

**(c)** Let $A= \begin{bmatrix}a&b\\ c&d\\ \end{bmatrix}$ and $B= \begin{bmatrix}c&d\\ a&b\\ \end{bmatrix}$. Since $\begin{bmatrix}0&1\\ 1&0\\ \end{bmatrix}\cdot \begin{bmatrix}0&1\\ 1&0\\ \end{bmatrix}$ $=\begin{bmatrix}1&0\\ 0&1\\ \end{bmatrix}$ $=I_2$, we have $D(I_2)$ $=\left[D\left(\begin{bmatrix}0&1\\ 1&0\\ \end{bmatrix} \right) \right]^2=1$. Which implies $D\left(\begin{bmatrix}0&1\\ 1&0\\ \end{bmatrix} \right)$ $=\pm1$. Since $D(I_2)=1$ and $D \left(\begin{bmatrix}0&1\\ 1&0\\ \end{bmatrix}\right)\neq D(I_2)$, we have $D \left(\begin{bmatrix}0&1\\ 1&0\\ \end{bmatrix}\right)=-1$. Since $\begin{bmatrix}0&1\\ 1&0\\ \end{bmatrix}\cdot \begin{bmatrix}a&b\\ c&d\\ \end{bmatrix}= \begin{bmatrix}c&d\\ a&b\\ \end{bmatrix} $, we have $$D\left(\begin{bmatrix}c&d\\ a&b\\ \end{bmatrix}\right)= D\left(\begin{bmatrix}0&1\\ 1&0\\ \end{bmatrix}\right)\cdot D\left(\begin{bmatrix}a&b\\ c&d\\ \end{bmatrix}\right)=-D\left(\begin{bmatrix}a&b\\ c&d\\ \end{bmatrix}\right).$$ Hence $D(B)=-D(A)$. Let $A= \begin{bmatrix}a&b\\ c&d\\ \end{bmatrix}$ and $B= \begin{bmatrix}b&a\\ d&a\\ \end{bmatrix}$. Since $\begin{bmatrix}a&b\\ c&d\\ \end{bmatrix}\cdot \begin{bmatrix}0&1\\ 1&0\\ \end{bmatrix}= \begin{bmatrix}b&a\\ d&c\\ \end{bmatrix} $, we have $$D\left(\begin{bmatrix}b&a\\ d&c\\ \end{bmatrix}\right)= D\left(\begin{bmatrix}a&b\\ c&d\\ \end{bmatrix}\right)\cdot D\left(\begin{bmatrix}0&1\\ 1&0\\ \end{bmatrix}\right)=-D\left(\begin{bmatrix}a&b\\ c&d\\ \end{bmatrix}\right).$$ hence $D(B)=-D(A)$. **Is my proof correct?**

I tried very hard to do exercise (d) and (e), but can’t prove it. Observating pattern of proofs of (a), (b) and (c), I think we have to multiply some “clever” matrix with given matrix in such a way that $D$ of result matrix is familiar. In (d), we have to find matrix $\begin{bmatrix}p&q\\ r&s\\ \end{bmatrix}$ such that $\begin{bmatrix}a&b\\ 0&0\\ \end{bmatrix} \cdot \begin{bmatrix}p&q\\ r&s\\ \end{bmatrix}$ $= \begin{bmatrix}0&0\\ 0&0\\ \end{bmatrix}$, I guess. If we take $\begin{bmatrix}b&b\\ -a&-a\\ \end{bmatrix}$, then that works but what is value of $D\left(\begin{bmatrix}b&b\\ -a&-a\\ \end{bmatrix}\right)$.

Comment: For b) I would write other way round $D(A)^2 = D(A^2) =D(0) =0$, and thus this implies $D(A) = 0$.

For c) yes, you correctly observed that interchanging rows/columns of $A$ corresponds to the multiplication of $A$ from the left/right by the matrix $w = \begin{pmatrix} 0 & 1 \\ 1 & 0 \end{pmatrix}$. And since you also correctly observed that $D(w) = -1$ this is exactly what c) asks for.

Comment: For a) you don't need exercise 12. You already proved that $D(0)=0$ or $1$. If $D(0)=1$ then for any matrix $A$ (in particular for our two matrices $I$ and $J$), $D(A)=D(A)D(0)=D(A0)=D(0)=1$, which contradicts the hypothesis $D(I)\ne D(J)$.

Comment: For d) try to use the following:
1) Assume $A$ is such a matrix with the elements $a$ and $0$ on its diagonal.
2) Now if you know a little about diagonalization, you can show that there exists an invertible matrix $S$, such that $SAS^{-1} = \begin{pmatrix} a & 0 \\ 0 & 0 \end{pmatrix}$. Now, what relation exists between $D(SAS^{-1})$ and $D(A)$?
3) So now, by c), if $B$ has just one non-zero entry, then $D(B) = \pm D(B')$ where $B'$ has the same non-zero entry somewhere else. Does that help you so far?

Comment: @AnneBauval Your proof is more elegant and easy than mine. I like it.

Comment: @MatyMangoo Thank you so much for the hint. I will definitely check those hints. I will take some time.

Comment: @MatyMangoo 1) $A$ is not necessarily diagonalizable, it may be similar to $\begin{pmatrix}0&1\\0&0\end{pmatrix}$. 2) Is your point 3 an attempt or a true hint? (I do not see where it goes, may be something like in copper.hat answer's?)

Comment: Thanks for the correction, you are definitely right, but its reparable. Point is we just need 3 entries 0. And 3) is a hint.

Comment: If you have 2 matrices and each has at most one non-zero entry and you can even (up to a sign when valued in $D$) chose where they are, you can chose them s.t. their product is the $0$-matrix.

Comment: *I was kind of automatically considering only the case $a \neq 0$ since otherwise we would already be in the situation where we have just one non-zero entry (at most).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Too long for a comment:

For (d): Let $E_{ij}$ be the matrix of zeros except with one in the $ij$ position. Let $S=E_{12}+E_{21}$ be the 'swap' matrix.

Show that $D(E_{11})$ is either zero or one.
Show that $D(SE_{11}) = D(E_{22}S)$ and since $E_{11} E_{22} = 0$ conclude that $D(E_{11})=0$.

If the top row of $A$ is zero then $E_{11}A = A$. Similar considerations work for the other situations.

For (e): If $A$ is singular then it can be reduced to a row echelon form (may need to swap rows) in which the lower row is zero.

Comment: Brilliant! Not only is it "to long for a comment", but a true answer. In d), for the preliminary proof that $D(E_{11})=D(E_{22})=0$, one may also use c) twice to say that $D(E_{11})=D(E_{22})$ (and then, as you did, $D(E_{11}E_{22})=0$).

Comment: @AnneBauval copper.hat answer and your proof of $D(E_{11})=0$ is really clever. But how is $E_{11}A=A$, given first row of $A$ is zero? I’m getting $E_{11}A=0$. Our whole point to prove $D(E_{11})=0$ was to show $D(A)=D(E_{11}A)=D(E_{11})D(A)=0\cdot D(A)=0$.

Comment: Ohh….. I found mistake. $E_{11}A=A$, if second row of $A$ is zero and $E_{22}A=A$, if first row of $A$ is zero.

Comment: And $AE_{11}=A$, if second column of $A$ is zero and $AE_{22}=A$, if first column of $A$ is zero.